# How to define keyspaces for a timeseries data in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

There are 100s of data points, each data point has its own seperate table with schema and queries as mentioned below:

### Current Schema in SQLite

- Table Name: Name of Data Point e.g. Tempearature
- Column-1: Name: Timestamp Type: TEXT (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ttt format) PRIMARY KEY
- Column-2: Name: Value Type: FLOAT
- Column-3: Name: Quality Type: TEXT ("GOOD", "BAD")

### Queries for SQLite

- SELECT * FROM *data-point-name*;
- SELECT * FROM *data-point-name* WHERE Timestamp BETWEEN *timesamp-1* AND *timestamp-2*;
- INSERT INTO *data-point-name* (Timestamp, Value, Quality) VALUES ("2016-01-01 00:00:05.254", 123.25454, "GOOD"); (this is an example)

Currently I have SQLite db where I have a table per data-point with above schema, essentially I have 100s of tables. This way reads/writes are not disturbing queries running on different data-points.

How to translate this schema to be used in Cassandra?

Comment: Can you show us your current schema and query you are using ?

Comment: @GuillaumeS : Added schema and queries that I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can store all your data points in a single table :

```
CREATE TABLE datapoints (
    datatype varchar(30),
    time timestamp,
    value float,
    quality varchar(4),
    PRIMARY KEY (datatype, time)
);
```

With this structure, you can run queries like :

```
SELECT * 
FROM datapoints 
WHERE datatype = 'data-point-name';

SELECT * 
FROM datapoints 
WHERE datatype = 'data-point-name'
   AND time >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
   AND time <= '2016-01-02 00:00:00';
```

But with this structure, cassandra will partition data by datapoint name,
if you have many points, your partition will be huge and you can have query performence issues.

You can also refine the partitionning by decompose the time :

```
CREATE TABLE datapoints (
   datatype varchar(30),
   year int,
   month int,
   day int,
   milisecondsinday int,
   value float,
   quality varchar(4),
   PRIMARY KEY ((datatype, year, month, day), milisecondsinday)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (milisecondsinday ASC);
```

In this case, this structure allow cassandra to store datas in more small partition than the first exemple and it's more powerfull if you query you data by day :

```
SELECT *
FROM datapoints
WHERE datatype = 'data-point-type'
   AND year = 2016
   AND month = 1
   AND day = 1;
```

get all points for 'data-points-type'
for the `2016-01-01`
between `00:00 AM` and `01:00 AM`

```
SELECT *
FROM datapoints
WHERE datatype = 'data-point-type'
   AND year = 2016
   AND month = 1
   AND day = 1
   AND milisecondsinday >= 0
   AND milisecondsinday <= 3600000;
```

Of course, you can partition by day (like exemple) or others time scale (hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds). If you can, small partition will be good for performence.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Great, thanks ! I was indeed looking for something like you've put together for me and also similarly suggested here: https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling with only one difference that I'm going to have a table per data point , as shown in this link where a table is created for temperature.